# Story about man living in an apartment with the Sun going red giant

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a book once that had a man living in an apartment in a mostly abandoned/empty apartment building, one of the last people alive in the world or so I believe, due to the sun going red giant early? I don't remember for sure the specific reason but I know that the planet was overheating to the extent it was regularly 110F+ outside. He had stayed in his apartment, and there were a couple other people in there as well - I distinctly remember a drug addict couple (meth?) a floor or two down from him, that he had occasional interactions with.

I read this story probably around 4 or 5 years ago, and I think it had the same general vibes as something written by Larry Niven or Phillip K. Dick maybe. I'm unsure the actual era of the book but definitely before 2000, I'm going to guesstimate '70s.

I have no clue how it ended or what the central conflict of the story was. It was definitely an average human on Earth though, unless the ending twist was that they weren't on Earth all along. It was probably set in the '70s or so, since I remember relatively modern appliances (microwave, fridge, radio, etc.) and nothing super futuristic.

I think it was a short story, but it might've been a novella. Not sure.

Comment: Rings a bell for me also. If it helps, in addition to Niven and PKD, I’ve read a lot of Bradbury and Sturgeon

Comment: I think the closest Niven one is "Inconstant Moon" but the timescale is much shorter (i.e. "the solar event" happens during the night) whereas this question seems about a story where "the solar event" is much slower and is ongoing. I don't think he did any similar story to this so I would agree with your "like Niven but not Niven" guess...

Comment: The sun flaring up hot with just a few survivors reminds me of James Blish's "Testament of Andros" from 1953,

Comment: @ToddWilcox I don't think it's Bradbury, but yeah the same writing style sounds about right. Haven't read any of Sturgeon. Might be Forward though.

Comment: @AdamT That sounds plausible. I haven't really read a lot of Niven's stuff, so I'm not entirely sure what he's got. Thanks for helping narrow it down.

Comment: @H.A.Treesong It's probably not that guy - I can't really find a good description, but I'm substantially too young to have read that I think. I haven't really read any of the more obscure authors. Also, that looks more scifi than I was remembering - mine was a little bit more of contemporary fiction/very near future with little to no scifi elements other than the sun going boom if I recall correctly.

Comment: It sounds a bit like the season three episode "The Midnight Sun" of The Twilight Zone, written by Rod Serling.  That's not the Sun going red giant, though; instead, the Earth's orbit has been disrupted and the Earth is moving closer to the Sun.  Is it possibly an adaptation of that script?  I know some of them were adapted to short stories and graphic novels.

Comment: Not sure it will help, but perhaps it's the same story as this question:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272266/1960s-or-1970s-short-story-earth-is-being-evacuated-because-of-an-expanding-sun

Comment: @Jim wow, I'd forgotten about this question. Still never found it though! Not that twilight zone episode - I've seen it before. This one definitely had like a drug addict couple or something along those lines, and I believe it was longer as well. The water thing from the linked question could maybe be part but it had enough development I don't think that would've been the punchline or anything.