# 1960s or 1970s short story; Earth is being evacuated because of an expanding Sun

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the 1970s, I read a short story about a young man who missed the last evacuation ship off Earth. The Sun was expanding and Earth was heating up too much to sustain life. Humans were being moved to another planet, but this guy missed his ride.

In the beginning of the story, he woke up late, realized that he had missed his scheduled spaceship, and wasn't really sure what to do next. As he was trying to figure out his next move, he became thirsty, and turned on the cold water tap to fill his glass. As he waited for the water to run cold, he realized it would never happen, because the ambient temperature of Earth had risen too high.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall whether you read this in an anthology or a magazine?

Comment: i think an anthology, unless there were book sized sci fi magazines at that time

Comment: Not sure it will help, but perhaps it's the same story as this question:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253471/story-about-man-living-in-an-apartment-with-the-sun-going-red-giant